# Grabbing Refferer's URL - PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to grab statistics on my site and I need a way in PHP to assign just the referrer URL to a variable. All I want is just the "www" or subdomain, the domain, and the tld... I.E. www.facebook.com instead of http://www.facebook.com/BLAH-BLAH/?blah=blah

Comment: Take a look at `parse_url` http://us2.php.net/parse_url It should help you get what you want!

Comment: @MetalFrog I see where your going with the parse_url but I am a bit confused on how to grab just the URL instead of all that host and password stuff. Thanks

Comment: it looks like btantlinger's given you a concise example. That'll do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$parts = parse_url($referer);
echo $parts['host']; //should echo example.com, or whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$ref = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
$host = null;
if ($ref != null) {
  $parse = parse_url($ref);
  $host = $parse["host"];
}
?>
```

and then you have `$host` to work with